# How do I update an item that was passed to a function?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, fetch, jsx

I am trying to update the item by adding + 1 without letting a `fetch` update the item. Basically, when I `fetch`, the backend updates the number by + 1 and instead of doing it that way, I want to do it through the frontend.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.anim_like(item)} <-- Passing all items from dataSource
  style={{position:'absolute',  height: '100%', width: '100%', right: 140, bottom: 50}}
>
  <Animation
    progress={item.progress}
    source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
    style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute'}}
    resizeMode={`contain`}
   />
</TouchableOpacity>
<Text>{item.likes}</Text> <-- Getting likes from the fetched data




anim_like = (item) => {
  Animated.timing(item.progress, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 1500,
    easing: Easing.linear,
  }).start();
  fetch(`https://www.example.com/React/user-like.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      post_id : item.id,
    })  
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      //this.refetchData(); <-- Current way to update item.likes
      item.likes = item.likes + 1;<-- Want to update it this way by + 1 without updating the full fetch data
    }).catch((error) => {   
  });
}
```

Naturally, that `anim_like` once clicked, will add + 1 in the backend. The way I currently have it is that once it updates in the backend, refetch the results and display it. Which causes a slower response time.

Here is the fetch api:

```
fetch(`https://www.example.com/React/user.php` , {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }

  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        user_image:  responseJson[0].user_images.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0)})) <-- This adds a unique animated.value to each user 
        },function() {

        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //console.error(error);
    });
```

I use `this.state.user_image` for retrieving all present data from the backend and put it in the `renderItem` in `Flatlist`. I display which data I want, for example the above code, `item.likes` or `item.progress`.

It is also responsible and converting it to a JSON array and use the data in React Native:

```
[{
  "food":"pizza",
  "who":"Person",
  "user_images":[{
    "id":"114",
    "username":"Hannah_L123",
    "images":"resized_1522-20131219-creativity.jpg",
    "date":"12\/04\/2017",
    "likes": "20"
  }]
}]
```

If any of this is confusing, I will be glad to shine some light on it! Thank you!

Comment: So basically you want to add 1 before you get the response from the backend?

Comment: @bwalshy Well add 1 without getting the response from the backend. Instead the front end will show that response and that should eliminate the extra step of calling another fetch.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams how to get the latest like value from backend without accessing it before , i think method you make is one of the solution

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. Is the second code snippet (the one you labeled the fetch api) the code for `refetchData()`?

Comment: @MaulanaPrambadi I just refetch the same api basically. It's a solution, yes, but the response time is really slow because I have so much data. It'd be great if I could just update the like value directly.

Comment: @bwalshy No. `refetchData()` is actually my 3rd code snippet. Which is what I use for `refeteching` as I all it. This updates the like values, but it also update other values which causes a slower response time

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, the pattern you'd probably want to do is not call `refetchData` at all. You'd probably want your `React/user-like.php` endpoint to return the item that was liked (assuming it also holds how many likes it has). Then when that request is done, update the likes on the item with the new number from the new item returned from the API.

Comment: Another possible solution is to just update the number of likes by 1 before you call `refetchData()`

Comment: Sounds like you could just increment your state before refetching and when you get the response on the refetch you can check if it's correct corresponding to the number showing in the frontend.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams i think the post proses from your backend should return last count like so you can set new state from data that return from your backend without fetch the like

Comment: @bwalshy I just use `user-like` to update the backend, so that's needed. I don't want it to return anything. And like A. Larsson said, I want to do something like that, but how can I get the item.likes in `this.state`?

Comment: Where is `refetchData()` in your code? can you update your question with it please.

Comment: @MaulanaPrambadi I don't want the backend to return anything, but just let the frontend increment by number once I click `anim_like`. Yes the backend does update, but it shouldn't return that updated result.

Comment: @SGhaleb All it is, is the fetch api in a function

Comment: It's good practice to return the updated item with APIs, but I won't argue. But why can't you setState after fetching from your `React/user-like.php` endpoint? What's stopping you from doing updating the number of likes before `refreshCount()`?

Comment: @bwalshy Well, if I am correct, if I do setState after it updates in the backend then wouldn't `<Text>{item.likes}</Text>` stay the same value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to update the likes without updating your server.

You can achieve this by the following:

Create a state in your class.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        animLike: ''
    }
}
```

Change the event to:

```
onPress={this.updateApi}
```

so it is like this.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={this.updateApi} //<-- Passing like to
    style={{position:'absolute',  height: '100%', width: '100%', right: 140, bottom: 50}}>
        <Animation
            progress={item.progress}
            source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
            style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute'}}
            resizeMode={`contain`}
        />
</TouchableOpacity>
<Text>{this.state.animLike}</Text> // <--Getting likes from state
```

add a function in your class which will update Frontend and backend

```
updateApi = () =>{
    this.setState({animLike:+1})
    this.anim_like(this.state.animLike)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but `{this.state.animLike}` will not have the current "likes" from the JSON and it doesn't update in the backend

Comment: @SgGHaleb is there a way I can do this method while still having {item.likes} instead of {this.state.animLike}? It's just that it's blank and {item.likes} displays the current likes.

Comment: Actually this code could work if I can just get all the likes from the json array and put it in a state, but how do I do that?

Comment: add this to your fetch response `this.setState({
        animLike:  responseJson[0].user_images.likes) }` , But i think this will take you back to your first problem.

Comment: Yeah it does...`responseJson[0].user_images.likes` is undefined so I modified to this: `responseJson[0].user_images[0].likes`. But that does console log the all of the likes, just one. I apologize for all of this. Truly, the why I had it setup is a better way to go, but the fetch response is just slow.

Comment: Have you considered using componet life cycles such as `componentDidUpdate(){//fetch data POST}` or `componentDidMount(){//get Data}` etc... or setState callback so you set the state first then call function `this.setState({ animLike: this.animLike.count+1 }, () => this.anim_like(this.state.animLike))` . If you can update your question to have the full class component code for better understanding, then that is helpful for others, as snippets don't tell the big picture

Comment: Yeah I am using componentDidUpdate for the fetch call

Answer (score 0):

If the `item` is in your state you can update it like

```
//where you do item.likes = item.likes +1  you Must do
this.setState(prevState => ({
    item: {
        ...prevState.item,
        likes: prevState.item.likes + 1
    }
}));
```

If it is in an Array like ˋthis.state.items`passed rendered by`renderItem` then you can

```
//where you call anim_like you have to pass the index of the item like
this.anim_like(item, index)

//in your anim_like function where you do item.likes = item.likes + 1 you must do
let items = this.state.items; // to take the items and manipulate it
item.likes = item.likes + 1; //update likes for the current item
items[index] = item; // update the item in the array with the index passed in parameter of anim_like
this.setState({
    items
}); // update the state to have your screen refresh
```

But i recommend to use a dedicated Component for the item which has his proper method like anim_like because this way it’ll re-render all your screen rather than just the liked component.

In your case I think `this.state.items` is `this.state.user_image`

Comment: Much appreciated, but this is the error I got: `TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'prevState.item.likes' )`

Comment: @LaneyWilliams try my second approach but it seems in your case you don’t `items` in your state but `user_image` so you have to adapt my code to yours.

Comment: Yeah, it would be easier if I can have all of the likes from the json array and put it in a state. Is that possible with my current code above in the question?

Comment: I understand. I mean the old way I had it setup works, but the fetch response time is so slow. I can get the likes by doing this: responseJson[0].user_images[0].likes, but it doesn't get all of them.

Comment: You increment likes before executing fetch and if error or something wrong happen you decrement maybe in your catch statement.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do with another function. This code could work if I could access all the "likes" and put it in a state though.

Comment: yes they are! But It's coming from the: responseJson[0].user_images.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0)})). I just want likes in it's own list: responseJson[0].user_images[0].likes

Comment: But just create! With the map method I think you can do that

Comment: Yeah I did, but when I put the state in place of {item.likes}, I got objects are not valid as a react child and then I used `toString()` and that made everything into `[Object]` instead of a number

Comment: It's the same the thing as `this.state.user_image` except I changed it in the backend. Don't worry about it. It doesn't matter because it prints out everything and is not unique

Comment: Ok if it is the same and `this.state.user_image` 's content is like `[{
    "id":"114",
    "username":"Hannah_L123",
    "images":"resized_1522-20131219-creativity.jpg",
    "date":"12\/04\/2017",
    "likes": "20"
  }]` then you just have to do `this.state.user_image.map(item => item.likes)` to have an array of likes.

Comment: Yeah I did that. Thank you. I just have to just figure out how to speed up the fetch time

Comment: Okay cool! To speed up you can reduce the code returned and code executed in your backend. If it is just a like you return nothing! The RESTFul Standard day that the POST PUT or DELETE request must return nothing.

Comment: That's what I do. I limit to own like 30 results, but how can increase the speed without limiting?